# Set variable column in search looping through worksheets not working,

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find

I'm working on a macro that needs to find every value in a range in "sheet1" and search for it in all the sheets of the workbook (may be up to 7 sheets), as it takes too long, looking for the values in the entire sheets, I would like to reduce the search field on each sheet up to one variable column with header IP.

This is the macro I have so far, but I can't get it to work only on that specified range, however, removing those lines makes the macro work ok.

Thank you in advance.

```
Sub findInventory()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strWhat, rngFound, mString As String
Dim rngSearch, osfind, rfind, rfcol As Range
Dim i, x As Integer
Dim LastRow, oscol, lcol, e, lrowA, remChar, fcol As Long




Sheets("GVM Report").Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 2).EntireColumn.Insert
Sheets("GVM Report").Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = "INVENTORY"
Sheets("GVM Report").Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, 2).Value = "OPSDB"

Set rfind = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("GVM Report").Rows("1:3").Find(What:="IP", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
lcol = rfind.Column

Set osfind = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("GVM Report").Rows("1:3").Find(What:="OS*", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
oscol = osfind.Column

LastRow = Sheets("GVM Report").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To LastRow

strWhat = Sheets("GVM Report").Cells(x, lcol)
    For Each ws In Worksheets
    Set rfcol = ws.Rows("1:3").Find(What:="IP", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    fcol = rfcol.Column
    With ws.Columns(fcol)
    Select Case ws.name
    Case "Operations", "Data", "FYI all OS", "Unique Values", "GVM Report"

    Case Else
       Set rngSearch = ws.Cells.Find(What:=strWhat)
        If strWhat <> "" Then
            If Not rngSearch Is Nothing Then
                i = i + 1
                If i = 1 Then
                    rngFound = rngSearch.Worksheet.name
                Else
                    rngFound = rngFound & " | " & rngSearch.Worksheet.name
                End If
                    End If

        End If

                Sheets("GVM Report").Cells(x, 2) = rngFound


    End Select
    End With
    Next ws
    rngFound = ""
    i = 0
Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I can replicate your error, but I've tidied up your code a little and it might be useful for you, so here it goes:

```
Sub findInventory()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsGVM As Worksheet: Set wsGVM = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GVM Report")
Dim strWhat As String, rngFound As String, mString As String
Dim rngSearch As Range, osfind As Range, rfind As Range, rfcol As Range
Dim i As Integer, x As Long, LastRow As Long, oscol As Long, lcol As Long, fcol As Long

wsGVM.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(, 2).EntireColumn.Insert
wsGVM.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = "INVENTORY"
wsGVM.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, 2).Value = "OPSDB"

Set rfind = wsGVM.Rows("1:3").Find(What:="IP", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not rfind Is Nothing Then lcol = rfind.Column

Set osfind = wsGVM.Rows("1:3").Find(What:="OS*", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not osfind Is Nothing Then oscol = osfind.Column

LastRow = wsGVM.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To LastRow
    strWhat = wsGVM.Cells(x, lcol)
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Set rfcol = ws.Rows("1:3").Find(What:="IP", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rfcol Is Nothing Then
            fcol = rfcol.Column
            With ws.Columns(fcol)
                Select Case ws.Name
                    Case "Operations", "Data", "FYI all OS", "Unique Values", "GVM Report"
                    ''''
                    Case Else
                        If strWhat <> "" Then
                            Set rngSearch = .Find(What:=strWhat)
                            If Not rngSearch Is Nothing Then
                                i = i + 1
                                If i = 1 Then
                                    rngFound = rngSearch.Worksheet.Name
                                Else
                                    rngFound = rngFound & " | " & rngSearch.Worksheet.Name
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                        wsGVM.Cells(x, 2) = rngFound
                End Select
            End With
        End If
    Next ws
    rngFound = ""
    i = 0
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! but in both cases it brigns no information, although before setting the column, it brought  proper results in the column "INVENTORY", it's like is not finding the proper results, the column ranges contain ip addresses, and upon matching the ip, it should bring the sheet name where the value was found.

Comment: Thank you, it worked as wonder!! I have been trying with an already trimmed report! I tried again with the full report and brings the proper results!

Answer (score 0):

I did a test with dummy'ed up data and got the following results:

```
INVENTORY
Sheet2 | Sheet3
Sheet2
Sheet3
```

which is consistent with what I would expect given the dummy data I created. Perhaps there are leading, trailing spaces or other non-visible difference that cause a data mismatch on cells that appear to be equal?